# PayPal error 400

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to connect a website to paypal via rest-api-sdk-php 1.13.0, and always get this error when hit the checkout button for making a payment:

400{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"Incoming JSON request does not map to API 
... accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment

As i am new to paypal integration, i write my code according to manual instructions from paypal developers page and some tutorials found on the web.

My PHP code for the secret key is:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

define('SITE_URL', 'http://localhost:8888/segundo_mercado');

$paypal = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        'ZDSFE7B...',
        'Xcfr6bG...'
    )
);
```

And Also for the payment operation:

```
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;

require 'app/start.php';

if(!isset($_POST["price"])){
die();
}

$product = 'Produto';
$price = $_POST['price'];
$shipping = 4.00;

$total = $price + $shipping;

$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$item = new Item();
$item->setName($product)
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setPrice($price);

$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems([$item]);

$details = new Details();
$details->setShipping($shipping)
->setSubtotal($price);

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setTotal($price)
    ->setDetails($details);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->SetAmount($amount)
    ->setItemList($itemList)
    ->setDescription('Segundo Mercado pagamento')
    ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(SITE_URL . '/success.php?success=true')
    ->setCancelUrl(SITE_URL . '/success.php?success=false');

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
    ->setTransactions($transaction);

try{
    $payment->create($paypal);
} catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getCode(); // Prints the Error Code
    echo $ex->getData(); // Prints the detailed error message 
    die($ex);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    die($ex);
}

$approvalUrl = $payment->getApprovalLink();
```

I think the problem is in the price or shipping values being passed has they come from a HTML form, but i tested the values and they are POSTED from the submit button.

I'm trying to connect to SANDBOX (not live).

It has been a long day, since 10am trying to solve this issue without luck.

Comment: Should `setTotal($price)` be `setTotal($total)`? Also I'd sanitize the POST value just in case: `$price = floatval($_POST['price']);`

Comment: Changed the code without luck. It throws the same error 400 message.
You are right setTotal is the full amount, but it doesn't worked anyway. Still stuck :(

Comment: I think i did everything by "the book", but it is not working, and the error in the try block isn´t very read friendly...

Comment: Sorry. Ben trying to see if I see any goofs, but that rest object with a payment transaction can be long winded (even in its shortest form)... so many places for it to go wrong. Cant help but wonder if you might have added a group that doesn't pertain to that transaction type... but the docs are almost as confusing to translate to php as well.

Comment: I see... It's a pain in the...

Comment: Just solved it...
It was a minor thing.
->setTransactions([$transaction]);
$transaction must be inside [...].

Comment: Woop. I was looking at your [$item] thinking it shouldn't be in an array, but after digging into the sdk, I realized it needs to be an array. But then you spotted that with transaction, so good work!

Answer (score 4):

**Just solved it...**
It was a minor thing.
->setTransactions([$transaction]);
$transaction must be inside [...].

Comment: Good catch man. Sometimes the SDKs make the general docs confusing (since the docs dont say anything about an array of such, using such-n-such method of some language SDK!). Glad you got it figured!

Comment: Yeah, it was amazing :)
Just figured if it was some kind of array and try it... It's woking very well right now :)